# deploying keycloak in a production ready environement using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am currently trying to deploy keycloak using docker-compose.

I wrote this docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  loadBalancer:
    image: nginx:1.19.6
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  auth:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    environment:
      - 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin'
      - 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin'
      - 'DB_VENDOR=postgres'
      - 'DB_ADDR=database'
      - 'DB_PORT=5432'
      - 'DB_DATABASE=keycloak'
      - 'DB_USER=keycloak'
      - 'DB_PASSWORD=password'
    command:
      - start-dev
      # - start
      # - --import-realm
      # volumes:
      #   - /home/keycloak/realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres:13.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /home/keycloak/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I do not see any warning or error, but the problem is that keycloak does not seems to connect to the database, do you have any clue what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the old environment variables for Keycloak.  If you take a look [this page](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db) and go to the `db-password` section (and then open it), you'll see:

[image]

I can't find docs to tell me when this changed from `DB_PASSWORD` but I think it was part of the Quarkus switchover.  I have:

```
KC_DB: postgres
KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/keycloak
KC_DB_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN:  ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
KC_HOSTNAME: auth.domain.tld
KC_PROXY: edge
```

where `db` is the name of my Postgresql database service within the `docker-compose.yml` file.

My complete `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./create_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN:  ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
#      KC_HOSTNAME: auth.myserver.tld
      KC_PROXY: edge

    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --hostname-url=http://localhost:8080
```

with my `.env` file looking like:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

DATABASE_USERNAME=keycloak
DATABASE_PASSWORD=keycloak
KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
```